# Where to put external API calls in layered architecture spring boot

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I have a SpringBoot application that have four layers; Domain, Controller, Service and Repository.

I'm using controllers to create endpoints for the clients, but within the application I would like to do some external API calls using REST to an external API that I don't want to directly expose for my clients.

Where in the structure would you go about implementing such external calls? I was discussing with a friend that it might be a good idea to create an adapter package of some sort, and call it within the service layer, but I'm not exactly sure.

Answer (score 4):

I would argue in most cases, this would be in your service layer, but again this is highly case dependent, if not, opinion based.

By definition, service layer supposed to ***serve*** you. This means that when a request arrives in your application's ***controller*** layer (which handles communications with the outside world) the controller layer is only supposed to transfer the data (in the proper format, e.g serialization, deserialization) and delegate the work to service layer (and obviously vice versa, transfer the outcome to the outside world).

***Domain*** and ***repository*** layers are quite out of the scope for an external rest call to be placed. Domain layer is supposed to model your data, and repository is generally for abstracting the storage of it.

Now about service layer, I would argue that this is where your application logic is. This is where you choose to store the data (go the repository, e.g.) or go to the external rest service.

However, just a point to highlight the situation's case dependency: Elasticsearch works with a rest interface, could be considered as a data store. So where do we place the calls made to it? Spring framework chooses to represent these calls in repository classes, and so would I.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it in service or data access layer. If the external API call is just to fetch data, you can make the external API call from your data access layer. But if it is for anything other than data access, you can do it from service layer.

You can create an adapater class for converting the data received from external service call to a format used within your application.